# django save imagefile in static dir

Tags: django, static, imagefield

I have some images i retrieve from http://image.eveonline.com/ that i want to save. Now part of those will be static, while others might change.
Instead of pulling all static images from their site, i want to do this when they are needed (if they are not saved yet)

How can i tell my model to save the imagefield in static or in media

Example model:

```
class ItemIcon(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey("items.Item")
    size = models.IntegerField(choices=settings.IMAGE_SIZES)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True) #The url to the evesite
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/images/items/")
```

(this model should be saved in static)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to set your `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` in your settings.py and then define your image field like this:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="items")
```

Note that you dont need to add the whole path to `upload_to` attribute, Django will append the absolute path for you.  And you need to have a folder named `items` inside your media folder.

If you want to save images in `STATIC_ROOT`, try this:

```
from django.conf import settings

fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

class ItemIcon(models.Model):
   item = models.ForeignKey("items.Item")
   size = models.IntegerField(choices=settings.IMAGE_SIZES)
   url = models.URLField(unique=True) #The url to the evesite
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to="items",storage=fs)
```

Comment: I got my media working. I was just wondering how i could let an imagefield save to STATIC_URL/STATIC_ROOT